# Extracting the line when 1st word of the line matches with given formats (PERL)

Tags: regex, perl, extract

I have a file as shown in the sample file TEST.txt

```
TEST.txt
top.s.1 { i go to home >85

jungle.lion and city }

dog7.1.e {dalmition <101

white and black }

cars_1.3.bmw_r { very good car =10

merc is merc.r.5_two }
```

I want to extract the lines that start with a word/field having **two "."** . The example output is as shown in OUT.txt

```
OUT.txt
 top.s.1 { i go to home >85
 dog7.1.e {dalmition <101
 cars_1.3.bmw_r { very good car =10
```

I tried to extract it using this regex

```
perl -ne '/^\w+.*?\.\w\.\d+.*?/ig && print' TEST.txt > OUT.txt
```

It missed to match few of the expressions. Can anyone help me in getting the desired??

NOTE:this is just a sample input file so this oneliner may work for this but it is not accurate enough to find all the strings in my original file.

Comment: would the following be a match - xyz..cfv..dfr {good}

Comment: Having only two dots or does rest of string not matter?

Comment: Is your primary goal here to find "headers", i.e. the string before the `{ ... }` block? If so, it might be prudent to include the blocks in the regex.

Comment: There are thousands of lines in which i have to extract the line starting with the string having two dots as mentioned. The format of the string in the begining is some kind of name which has to be extracted.  @bruce i dont want to match the line in your comment as it has 2 consecutive dots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex `/^\w+.*?\.\w\.\d+.*?/ig` expects a string of alphanumerics followed by *anything of any length*, then a dot, a single alphanumeric, another dot, then some digits, then anything. The `/i` modifier is unnecessary because you have no alpha characters in the pattern, and the `/g` is unecessary because the `/^/` means it can match only once.

Remove the `.*?` and change the `\w` and the `\d+` to `\w+` and it should work.

This will do what you require. It expects the input file as a command-line parameter

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<>) {
  print if /^\w+\.\w+\.\w+[^\w.]/;
}
```

or as a command-line program:

```
perl -ne 'print if /^\w+\.\w+\.\w+[^\w.]/' TEST.txt
```

Comment: This works fine for me.. I made few minute changes to work exactly the way  i wanted... Thank u so much.. :)

Answer (score 0):

With `awk`:

```
awk '{if ($1 ~ /.*\..*\..*/) {print}}' TEST.txt
```

the test checks the desired pattern on the first field

Comment: I am not familiar about this.. But can i use the same kind in perl

Comment: There is no `awk` tag on this question, and your pattern matches any line that contains two dots *anywhere*

Answer (score 0):

If your main goal is to check the "headers" for the blocks, I think it is a good idea to first parse the headers and blocks into a hash. After that is done, you can check the hash keys for periods `.` as required:

```
> perl -MData::Dumper -nlwe 'if (/^\s*([\w.]+)\s*({\s*.*)/) { 
    $key = $1; $a{$key} = $2;
    } else { 
    $a{$key} .= $_ } }{ print Dumper \%a;' data.txt
```

**Output:**

```
$VAR1 = {
      'cars_1.3.bmw_r' => '{ very good car =10merc is merc.r.5_two } ',
      'top.s.1' => '{ i go to home >85jungle.lion and city }',
      'dog7.1.e' => '{ dalmition <101white and black }'
};
```

Post-processing of the keys would be something like:

```
@keys = grep /\..*\./, keys %a;   # 2 or more periods
@keys = grep /^[^.]*\.[^.]+\.[^.]*$/, keys %a;  # exactly 2 periods
```

I opted to remove newlines from the blocks by using the `-l` option for visual effect, but if you feel they should remain, just remove `-l` from the command line switches.

Answer (score -1):

I would use the following regular expression:

```
perl -ne 'print if /^[^ .]*\.[^ .]*\./'
```

i.e. there can be anything at the beginning of the line that is not a space or a dot, or even nothing, then there is a dot, than again anything but a space or a dot, and then again a dot.